# Don't Group Single Rows in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a JQGrid that groups together certain rows. I use `group` to define what rows should grouped together, so for example, if there are three `2`s, it groups all `2`s together. However it's possible there could be only one `2`, in which case I wouldn't want it grouped, i.e. having the row under a group.

**My question is**, is it possible to have the grouping only be applied to certain rows and leave others alone?

Below is what I currently have:

```
colNames:['group', 'Description', 'File Sent to Customer', 'Date/Time', 'ATS', '# of Bib Records', '# of Items', 'Customer DB', 'Customer ID'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'group', index:'group'},
        {name:'description', index:'description'},
        {name:'fileSent', index:'fileSent', width:150},
        {name:'date', index:'date', width:160},
        {name:'ats', index:'ats', width:100},
        {name:'bibRecords', index:'bibRecords', width:100},
        {name:'items', index:'items', width:100},
        {name:'customerDB', index:'customerDB', width:240},
        {name:'customerID', index:'customerID', width:150}
    ],
    grouping:true,
    groupingView : {
        groupField : ['group'],
        groupColumnShow : [false],
        groupText : [''],
        groupCollapse : true,
        groupOrder: ['desc']
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your question interesting. So I wrote the solution which shows instead of the standard grouping (see [the starting demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideSomeGroupingHeaders0.htm))

[image]

the following:

[image]

The corresponding code is not so complex:

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var i, groups = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "groupingView").groups,
        l = groups.length,
        idSelectorPrefix = "#" + this.id + "ghead_0_";
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (groups[i].cnt === 1) {
            // hide the grouping row
            $(idSelectorPrefix + i).hide();
        }
    }
}
```

It uses one level grouping, but it can be changed in the same way to the multilevel grouping.

One warning about the resulting grid: you should be careful with sorting of the grid. The problem is that jqGrid sort the rows *inside of the group only*. So the above rows with hidden grouping headers seems be out of sorting process.

Comment: This works great, thank you! In case anyone is interested, I added `$(idSelectorPrefix + i).children().children().click();` just before `.hide()` so that the single rows can be seen when you have `groupCollapse : true`

Comment: @JesseJ: You are welcome! In case of usage `groupCollapse: true` I would just use `$(idSelectorPrefix + i).hide().next().show();` instead because the next row after the gruoping header row is the row which need be displayed. See [the demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideSomeGroupingHeaders1.htm).